# Word for making a sound out of the side of your mouth

Tags: single-word-requests

It is hard to describe the action, so here is [an example:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_76a5DQqVx8&t=1m52s)

What is the word or phrase that best describes this noise made by a person?

Comment: Are we talking about the sound which occurs at 1:53?

Comment: When you do that while working with a horse, we call that [clucking.](http://www.equestrianlife.com/videos/watch/295/Horse_Groundwork:_Lunging) The trainer clucks at about 1:29.

Answer (score 2):

How about tsk? It's a "dental click" pronounced tisk. I think you could also use cluck but it would probably depend upon the context.

Answer (score 0):

If the request relates generally to the making some kind of imitative sound then *mouth sound effect* might be the best and most obvious choice here. The clip shows a character imitating a vampire hiss (I assume) and [SFX Source](http://www.sfxsource.com/sound-effects/horror-sound-effects/monster-sound-effects/vampire-hiss-01-0-02.html) has a listing of "mouth sound effects, mouth sounds" including lots of vampire hisses (along with chattering teeth, clucking, pops and so on).

*Sound effect*, while shorter, could also mean a variety of sounds that the mouth can't make.

Answer (score -1):

Onomatopoeia -more details below
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia

Comment: *Onomatopoeia* is the *process* of creating words in imitation of sounds; it is not the word for the actual sound that is being requested.