# Expressions that are not words, but sounds

Tags: expressions, non-native-english, sounds, caribbean-english

Jamaican-style patois and derivations thereof seem to be on the rise again in British cities after a lull (I remember it being very popular in the 70s and early 80s). While on a trip to London I was struck by what native speakers of that idiom refer to as *kissing teef* [sic] - a sound made to indicate disapproval by sucking the tongue through clenched teeth.

This is analogous (I think) to 'tutting' in British English which although not strictly speaking a word, has become one and is included in the OED. Do these parts of speech have a name? And can anyone offer other examples of these in English or any other languages?

UPDATE: Just found [an academic paper on the subject](http://privatewww.essex.ac.uk/~patrickp/papers/KSTpapwww.pdf) which refers to them as *oral gestures*.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, and have been trying to find an appropriate term. All I can come up with is _paralanguage_ and _inserts_, but they both describe features different from those you have in mind.

Comment: Some examples on this site (search for 'tsk tsk'): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59684/why-do-we-write-tsk-for-the-sound-of-disapproval and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69096/word-for-making-a-sound-out-of-the-side-of-your-mouth and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58638/how-should-aargh-really-be-pronounced

Comment: You can add "oral gestures" as an answer to your own question.

Comment: *Surely* we can do better than 'oral gestures'? That just sounds **wrong**.

Comment: Sticking one's tongue out or baring one's teeth also constitute 'oral gesture', yet I feel they are a different order of communicative expression to teef[sic] kissing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps *non-verbal interjection*?

There are a number of expressions in American English that approximate a not-quite-verbal expression for disapproval.

> - tsk-tsk (when expressed as a a sucking sound made by pulling the tongue away from the roof of the mouth)
> - mmm-mmm (a short repeated humming sound, the second of which is descending in tone; a rising in tone indicates warning)
> - feh (a voiced exhale beginning with an *F* sound)
> - heh (a voiced exhale beginning with an *H* sound)

UPDATE: The original poster's addition of a possible name for the type of expression, *oral gestures*, is interesting. Several of the examples I list above are often accompanied by a negative head shaking.

Comment: +1. Can I add the (southern?) American 'mmm-hmm' which, to my UK English-accustomed ears indicates a sort of grim resignation. I'm thinking of wise old African-American women in films now.

Answer (score -3):

"Tch-tch-tch", which is commonly used to express disagreement/dissatisfaction.

Comment: I don't think this answers what part of speech the other expression occurs in.

Comment: What is "the other expression" ?

Comment: "sucking the tongue through clenched teeth" - most definitely not the same as *tch*